# Your account already has a valid iOS Distribution certificate - Xcode error msg with signing app

Tags: ios, xcode

When I try to use the 'Export > Save for Ad Hoc Deployment' option in Xcode I am presented with a dropdown menu where it says the following :

> To Save for Ad Hoc Deployment, select a Development Team to use for provisioning:

I only have a single option so once I click 'Choose' I get the following error message:

> Xcode attempted to locate or generate matching signing assets and failed to do so because of the following issues: Your account already has a valid iOS Distribution certificate

When logging into my iOS Developer account I can see I currently have 3 iOS Distribution Certificates (5 in total) and all currently valid (e.g they expire in the future).

The Mac I am using is new, plus all the mobile iOS apps were developed by external developers/teams therefore I'm not sure which certificates I can safely remove.

As the certificates would have been made on other machines I don't have access to it isn't possible for me to simply export the existing developer profiles on these other Mac's and have them installed on my Mac. I'm also unsure if i can revoke current certificates? What is the worst that can happen when revoking current certificates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with most error messages in Xcode regarding certificates, it is not very helpful. I would do the following:

- delete all the current certificates on your developer account
- create new ones on your new machine MANUALLY (not through Xcode, so use the Keychain), this will make sure that the keys that sign your certificates are in your current keychain
- update your provisioning profiles with the new certificates
- sync the new profiles within Xcode (Preferences -> Accounts)
- update your app settings

To this day I still manually do all my certificates and provisioning and while certainly not problem free, I don't seem to have nearly the nightmares that many people do. The only part of the process that I do let Xcode handle is to sync up the profiles.